# How to plot 2x2 confusion matrix with predictions in rows an real values in columns?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, confusion-matrix

I know that we can plot a confusion matrix with sklearn using the following sample code.

```
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix, ConfusionMatrixDisplay
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

y_true = [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1]
y_pred = [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1]

print(f'y_true: {y_true}')
print(f'y_pred: {y_pred}\n')

cm = confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred, labels=[0, 1])
print(cm)
disp = ConfusionMatrixDisplay(confusion_matrix=cm)
disp.plot()
plt.show()
```

[image]

What we have:

```
TN | FP
FN | TP
```

But I want the prediction label placed in a row or y-axis and the true or real value label in a column or x-axis. How can I plot this using Python?

What I want:

```
TP | FP
FN | TN
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) Here is one way of reversing TP/TN.

##### Code

```
"""
Reverse True and Prediction labels

References:
    https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/0d378913b/sklearn/metrics/_plot/confusion_matrix.py
    https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.ConfusionMatrixDisplay.html
"""

from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix, ConfusionMatrixDisplay
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

y_true = [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1]
y_pred = [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1]

print(f'y_true: {y_true}')
print(f'y_pred: {y_pred}\n')

# Normal
print('Normal')
cm = confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred, labels=[0, 1])
print(cm)
disp = ConfusionMatrixDisplay(confusion_matrix=cm)
disp.plot()

plt.savefig('normal.png')
plt.show()

# Reverse TP and TN
print('Reverse TP and TN')
cm = confusion_matrix(y_pred, y_true, labels=[1, 0])  # reverse true/pred and label values
print(cm)
disp = ConfusionMatrixDisplay(confusion_matrix=cm, display_labels=[1, 0])  # reverse display labels
dp = disp.plot()
dp.ax_.set(ylabel="My Prediction Label")  # modify ylabel of ax_ attribute of plot
dp.ax_.set(xlabel="My True Label")        # modify xlabel of ax_ attribute of plot

plt.savefig('reverse.png')
plt.show()
```

##### Output

```
y_true: [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1]
y_pred: [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1]

Normal
[[2 0]
 [1 3]]
```

[image]

```
Reverse TP and TN
[[3 0]
 [1 2]]
```

[image]

(2) Another way is by swapping values and plot it with sns/matplotlib.

##### Code

```
import seaborn as sns
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


y_true = [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1]
y_pred = [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1]

cm = confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred)
print(cm)
cm_11 = cm[1][1]     # backup value in cm[1][1]
cm[1][1] = cm[0][0]  # swap
cm[0][0] = cm_11     # swap
print(cm)

ax = sns.heatmap(cm, annot=True)

plt.yticks([1.5, 0.5], ['0', '1'], ha='right')
plt.xticks([1.5, 0.5], ['0', '1'], ha='right')

ax.set(xlabel='True Label', ylabel='Prediction Label')
plt.savefig('reverse_tp_tn.png')
plt.show()
```

##### Output

```
[[2 0]
 [1 3]]
[[3 0]
 [1 2]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by "Plot this", but if you're just trying to move the data elements you can do that with `iloc[]` and assignment

```
df

    0   1
0   TN  FP
1   FN  TP


df.iloc[0,0], df.iloc[1,1]=df.iloc[1,1],df.iloc[0,0]

df
    0   1
0   TP  FP
1   FN  TN
```

Comment: "plot this" means a confusion matrix with predictions in rows and real values in columns as a real plot not as text output

Comment: @Zion there is not any *plot* (real or not) in your question, only a text output. The post here has answered the question exactly as asked.

Answer (score 0):

[`ConfusionMatrixDisplay.from_predictions`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.ConfusionMatrixDisplay.html#sklearn.metrics.ConfusionMatrixDisplay.from_predictions) accepts several convenience parameters. To swap the order (*i.e.*, place True Positives on the top row of your confusion matrix) and change the title, axis labels, font size, and color bar, use code similar to

```python
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix, ConfusionMatrixDisplay

y_true = [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1]
y_pred = [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1]

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
cm = confusion_matrix(y_pred, y_true, labels=[1, 0])      # reverse labels here
disp = ConfusionMatrixDisplay(cm, display_labels=[1, 0])  # ... and here
disp.plot(ax=ax, colorbar=False, cmap='Blues', text_kw=dict(fontsize=28))

ax.set_title('My Confusion Matrix')
ax.set_xlabel('Predicted value')
ax.set_ylabel('Real value')

plt.show()
```

to produce

[image: Confusion matrix with True Positives (TP) on top]